# What would be the name for a shameful pride?

Tags: word-request

I am having a conversation about a struggle that a pioneer would have (to be more specific, [the status of Medical Sciences Stack Exchange](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1259/99)). I want to make this sentence:

> I'm saying this not to be __________ to ourselves, but to simply say that these are what every pioneer would have to get with

What would be a suitable word to fill the blank? Being a pioneer you will ultimately have a pride for that, but in this context it's distracting, or even going off the rail. I have thought about "hubris", but it's too strong.

Here is a list of synonyms of "pride": pleasure, joy, delight, gratification, fulfillment, satisfaction, sense of achievement, comfort, content, contentment

Comment: Colloquially, you could say, "I'm saying this not to **pat ourselves on the back**..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might say "self-congratulatory", and delete "to ourselves".